# Problem with enabling anonymous users to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication

I am trying to enable anonymous users to access the site or maybe some pages on the site and I have made the regular steps, but still it isnot working.

1. I have enabled anonymous on the web application.
2. Site settings -> Permission settings -> Anonymous Access -> Entire web site and also I've stopped the inheritance for the site

After that it's still not working.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: No help? i need it please.

Comment: what happens.. Is it asking for credentials or are you logged in automatically? or??

Comment: actually everytime i am trying to open the site..it's asking me for a user name and password while i am enabling anonymouse users as i mentioned above! 
help me plz.

Comment: ok. So you have set everything up like in this blog https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site 
If so, try to access a simple file as an image in a library.. If this is possible there is something on the site that referes to another place without anonymous access

Comment: i've did all those stpes that are in the link and its still not working.. i tried to configure it and actually it's working now on the local server , but not working on the host server, any Idea why ? and where is the problem ?